# rsyslog not write log after logrotate

Tags: logrotate

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-101-generic x86_64)

rsyslog not writing logfile mail.log after logrotate,
file mail.log is empty.

After restart rsyslog (service rsyslog restart) mail.log starting write.

config logrotate

```
/var/log/mail.info/var/log/mail.warn
/var/log/mail.err
/var/log/mail.log
{
rotate 48
weekly
missingok
notifempty
compress
delaycompress
sharedscripts
postrotate
    invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
endscript
}
```

I am changed postrotate in config file by this link https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/1506, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

The same question was asked and answered in Server Fault: [Log files randomly stops writing to log files](https://serverfault.com/questions/990464/log-files-randomly-stops-writing-to-log-files).

Apparently it's a [known bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=900586) that can be avoided by changing all occurrences of
`invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate` to `/usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate` in `/etc/logrotate.d/*`.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1209854)

Comment: This answers exactly the same question. Even though the question over at Server Faults sounds different, the issue is rsyslog not writing logs after logs are rotated.